# Unity 2D display "flash effect" above tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, effects

I want to apply a brighten effect above my scene.
My scene contains tiles, and I want to perform white flash for a few frames by code.

I have already tried this code:

```
private Tilemap tm;
...
tm = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
tm.color = new Color(0.5f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

This code darkens the scene by a certain color amount, but I wish to brighten it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not working because in Unity if you render an image (in your case tile) the original color of the image is when its color is white (255,255,255,255).
It means that if you change the color of an image it will add this color to this image.
For instance, if you set the color of an image to red, the image colors will become more similar to red than the original image.

As I see it you have 2 ways to perform the white flash:

A) Add another image of a white rectangle that covers all the screen and set it's alpha color to a low number (the lower the number the lighter flash effect).
In the editor disable this object's renderer and when you want to perform a flash effect enable this object from the code (You can improve this with animations or code to get a smooth flash animation).

B) Install the package "2D Light". This is an experimental package that allow you to render 2d light.
This package contains a lot of components that allow you to stimulate light.

Comment: thanks Shahar :)
not sure i want to use either - but you got me thinking...
can I use white SpriteShape object and put it above the tilemap - then I change the alpha to show or hide the SpriteShape?
Only problem is i don't know how to add a SpriteRenderer to a SpriteShape or other way to do this.
Any ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this.

I created a new PNG that only contains white shapes on a transparent background.
There are about 20 pieces that match the shapes of my level tilemap.
Now I just create a new (white) tilemap above the level tilemap in the shape of the highlight.
Then I set the alpha of the white tilemap in code.

It works :)